# How to use a reduce to filter fields in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I need to write a `reduce` function that takes an object and returns a new one but only with string-type fields.
E.g.

```
Input: { type: 'pilot', isActive: true }
Output: { type: 'pilot' }
Input: { isActive: true }
Output: {}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What issues are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

At the first step you need to verify the type of values of input object, and if they are not 'string' => put to the new Object. Also use "Object.keys" to apply reduce to object.

It can be look like:

```
const newObj = return Object.keys(obj).reduce(  
    (acc, rec) => {  
      if (typeof obj[rec] === 'string') {  
        return { ...acc, [rec]: obj[rec] }  
      }  
      return acc     
    },  
    {}
  )
```

You need only put this code to your function.

Comment: Is this considered a TS or JS solution?

Comment: Array reduce - it's actually the ES6 function.

Answer (score 1):

If not particular about `reduce`, using `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries` will simplify.

```js
const obj1 = { type: "pilot", isActive: true };
const obj2 = { isActive: true };

const filter = obj =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([, value]) => typeof value === "string")
  );

console.log(filter(obj1));
console.log(filter(obj2));
```